# Getting (500) Internal Server Error with webresponse object

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpresponse

Trying To Loading Html Content Of "http://links.casemakerlegal.com/states/CA/books/Case_Law/results?search[Cite]=214 Cal.App.3d 533" but HttpWebResponse object Giving This Error "(500) Internal Server Error" 
And Code Is------
request = WebRequest.Create(urlCheck); request.Timeout = 100000; response = request.GetResponse(); strmRead = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(),System.Text.Encoding.UTF8); result = strmRead.ReadToEnd();

Comment: if the web site is truly running, the feature and it's parameters of [/states/CA/books/Case_Law/results?search[Cite]=214 Cal.App.3d 533] must be wrong, it could cause server side error, I would suggest to check server side logs, it may give you some clues.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a tool like Wireshark or Ethereal, or the developer tools in your browser to investigate this further.  It is likely the browser is sending some values in the HTTP Header that your code is not, and the server is returning a 500 due to these missing values.  Try replicating all of the headers that the browser is using in your code to see if this resolves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually browser agent. try adding a valid browser agent to your request headers along with Accept and Accept-Encoding headers,

*Edit: For example:

```
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; WOW64; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1";
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate");
request.Headers.Add("Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en;q=0.8");
```